# Call a function after each loop with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a loop where I'm making an ajax post.  I want to execute the function "doSomething()" only after my loop (and the ajax posts inside each loop) are complete.

I'm thinking this is called a promise, but I'm just getting into jQuery after doing server side forever...

```js
 selectedRows.each(function(e) {
            var dataforpost = { groupId: selectedGroup.Id, 
            userName: userName, displayName: displayName };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddMemberToGroup")',
                type: "POST",
                data: dataforpost,
                success: function(data) {}
            });
        });
        
  // now when that loop is done, do something
  doSomething();
```

Comment: I would use a promise and the "then" method to do something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.when`:

```
$.when(selectedRows.each(function(e) {
  var dataforpost = { groupId: selectedGroup.Id, 
  userName: userName, displayName: displayName };

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddMemberToGroup")',
    type: "POST",
    data: dataforpost,
    success: function(data) {}
  });
})).then(function() {
  // now when that loop is done, do something
  doSomething();
});
```

OR you can keep track of the last loop and trigger a `done` function call:

```
selectedRows.each(function(i, e) {
  var dataforpost = { groupId: selectedGroup.Id, 
  userName: userName, displayName: displayName };

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddMemberToGroup")',
    type: "POST",
    data: dataforpost,
    success: function(data) {},
    done: function() {
      if (i == selectedRows.length - 1) {
        // now when that loop is done, do something
        doSomething();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam!  I couldn't get the first option to run, but I did get the second one to work with a minor edit.  I moved the selectedRows.length check to the success function.  I couldn't get done: to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Perharps helps:

```
  selectedRows.each(function(index, elem) {
        var dataforpost = { groupId: selectedGroup.Id, 
        userName: userName, displayName: displayName };

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddMemberToGroup")',
            type: "POST",
            data: dataforpost,
            success: function(data) {}
        });
        jqxhr.then(function() {
          console.log( index );
          if ((index+1) >= selectedRows.length){
             console.log('last');
             // now when that loop is done, do something
             doSomething();
          }
        });
    });
```